# In PowerShell, how do I get help on the "more" command usage?

Tags: powershell

When I use `more`, most commonly through `help`, there are certain keys that do special things (<kbd>q</kbd> ends the `more` command, <kbd>Enter</kbd> scrolls down etc.).

Is there a way in PowerShell itself to get help on these keys or do I need to Google it up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`more` in Powerhsell is just a function with following definition:

```
param([string[]]$paths)
$OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding

if($paths)
{
    foreach ($file in $paths)
    {
        Get-Content $file | more.com
    }
}
else
{
    $input | more.com
}
```

So at the command line, you should be able to do `more.com /?` and see help, with the following text in it, which is what you are looking for:

```
If extended features are enabled, the following commands
are accepted at the -- More -- prompt:

P n     Display next n lines
S n     Skip next n lines
F       Display next file
Q       Quit
=       Show line number
?       Show help line
<space> Display next page
<ret>   Display next line
```